# How to communicate with process in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, process, pipe

I had perfectly correct and working program around 5 years ago. At that point I stopped using it, I upgraded the OS, time passed, dust covered the code, and finally I dug it up just to discover it does not communicate with subprocess anymore.

Here is the code (simplified, but it shows the problem):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Creating the pipe for reading from the process" << std::endl;   
    const std::string pipe_name = "/tmp/proc_comm";
    {
        int res = mkfifo(pipe_name.c_str(),0777);
        assert(res==0);    
    }

    std::cout << "Launching subprocess" << std::endl;
    FILE *cmd_handle = popen(("espeak -x -q -z 1> "+pipe_name+" 2> /dev/null").c_str(), "w");
    assert(cmd_handle!=0);

    std::cout << "Opening the pipe" << std::endl;
    int pipe_id = open(pipe_name.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
    assert(pipe_id!=-1);

    const std::string message = "hello\n";

    std::cout << "Sending the message" << std::endl;
    if (!fwrite(message.c_str(),sizeof(char),message.length(),cmd_handle))
        assert(0);
    if (ferror(cmd_handle))
        assert(0);
    if (fflush(cmd_handle)!=0)
        assert(0);

    fd_set output_set;
    FD_ZERO(&output_set);
    FD_SET(pipe_id,&output_set);

    static timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    std::cout << "Selecting the pipe for reading" << std::endl;
    const int inputs = select(pipe_id+1, // max of pipe ids + 1
                              &output_set,0,0,&timeout);

    if (inputs==-1) // error
      assert(0);
    else if (inputs==0) // nothing to read
        assert(0); // HERE (*)
    else  
    {
        // we can only read from our pipe
        assert(inputs==1); 
        assert(FD_ISSET(pipe_id,&output_set));

        const int bufsize = 20000;
        char char_buf[bufsize];
        memset(char_buf,0,sizeof(char_buf));

        std::cout << "Reading from the pipe" << std::endl;
        const int count = read(pipe_id,char_buf,bufsize-1);

        if (count==-1) 
            assert(0);

        std::cout << "Read " << count << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles, it runs, the pipe for reading from the process is created and opened, the subprocess is launched, the message is sent but there is nothing to read from the process (the line `HERE (*)`).

**So how do you read from the process nowadays?** If possible I would like to keep the general workflow, i.e. using pipe for reading, and a process handle for writting to process.

Comment: How do you know the subprocesss sent something before your timeout?

Comment: @jxh, I can run the process in bash and evaluate the timeout. 10 seconds is more than enough. Besides it worked :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Perhaps the FIFO is empty at the moment of select() returns.

#### This simple experiment shows it.

- Running your code with the modified line 
  `FILE *cmd_handle = popen (("echo begin; espeak -x -q -z 1>" + pipe_name + " 2>/dev/null; echo end;").c_str (), "w");`.
- `cat < /tmp/proc_commn &; ./a.out;`
- Output is:

  Creating the pipe for reading from the process
  Launching subprocess
  Opening the pipe
  begin
  Sending the message
  Selecting the pipe for reading
  a.out: main.cpp:64: int main(): Assertion `0' failed.
   h@l'oU        *#### <--- Data in FIFO only after assertion.*
  end

#### Using pclose().

With addition of `pclose()` call, the problem disapears:

```
if (!fwrite(message.c_str(),sizeof(char),message.length(),cmd_handle))
    assert(0);
if (ferror(cmd_handle))
    assert(0);
if (fflush(cmd_handle)!=0)
    assert(0);

/* pclose added. */
if (pclose (cmd_hanlde) < 0)
{
    /* handle error. */
}

fd_set output_set;
```

#### So how do you read from the process nowadays?

I don't think, that your code became obsolete in any sense. I'm not an expert, so I don't have good answer on this question. But I hope, that this post will help you with solving your problem.

## Update.

#### Debugging with strace and espeak 1.46.2.

Running your code with strace (`strace -f ./a.out`) and any `select()` timeout:
Porcess 31985 is the parent process (main process).
Porcess 31987 is the child process (`espeak`).

```
# Child process starts trying to read from stdin.
[pid 31987] read(0,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31985] <... sync resumed> )        = 0
[pid 31985] write(1, "Sending the message\n",  ...
[pid 31985] fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 31985] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,  ...

# Main process writes message to the pipe.
[pid 31985] write(4, "hello\n", 6)      = 6

# Child process reads message from the pipe.
[pid 31987] <... read resumed> "hello\n", 4096) = 6
[pid 31985] write(1, "Selecting the pipe for reading:3"..., 3 ...
) = 33
[pid 31987] fstat64(1,  <unfinished ...>

# Main process calls select().
[pid 31985] select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {10, 0} <unfinished ...>
[pid 31987] <... fstat64 resumed> {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 31987] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ ...

# Child process calls read() again (second time).
# Seems like it waits another portion of input.
# Note: The previous input don't processed yet.
[pid 31987] read(0,  <unfinished ...>

# Despite big value of `select()` timeout, there is no data processing here.
# Select returns by timeout.
[pid 31985] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 31985] write(2, "a.out: main.cpp:69: i ...
) = 54
[pid 31985] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 31985] gettid()                    = 31985
[pid 31985] tgkill(31985, 31985, SIGABRT) = 0
[pid 31985] --- SIGABRT (Aborted) @ 0 (0) ---
```

#### Why there is no input processing in strace log?

Let's look at the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak/files/espeak/espeak-1.46/) of `espeak`. 
This is the code of reading input from `stdin` (src/espeak.cpp) (Assuming correctness of finding out mapping of command line arguments on a set of internal variables):

```
 728     // line by line input on stdin
 729     while(fgets(p_text,max,stdin) != NULL) // <--- * here first and second 
 730     {                                      // <--- * read() call.
 731         p_text[max-1] = 0;
 732         espeak_Synth(p_text,max,0,POS_CHARACTER,0,synth_flags,NULL,NULL);
 733 
 734     }
```

Comments about `espeak_Synth()` function (src/speak_lib.h:268):

```
 /*
  * Synthesize speech for the specified text.  
  * The speech sound data is passed to the calling      
  * program in buffers by means of the callback function specified by 
  * espeak_SetSynthCallback(). The command is asynchronous: 
  * it is internally buffered and returns as soon as possible.
  * ...
  */
```

`espeak_Synth()` is asynchronous function (thats why we see two `read()` calls in a row).
I assume that call of `espeak_Synth()`, should result in data written to `stdout` (after some delay). But it is not happening even with big value of the `select()` timeout. It's something strange here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help +1. I am not accepting your answer (I am really grateful, don't get me wrong) for now, because there is something odd with `select` -- you can increase timeout, and still it will report there is no data (despite there are!). As with `pclose` it terminates the process, so there would be big penalty for adding it to the workflow (think of thousands of request to a subprocess). You should be a able to launch subprocess (deamon) and communicate with it without killing it on each request. All in all you gave me great hints, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for all your help and work. I came to conclusion there is a subtle bug in espeak, and the communication itself is OK. I tried simple echo (mine) program which prints back the input and it is fine.